# "Page allocation stalls" Errors and System Freeze When Starting Game

Tags: ubuntu, memory, freeze, out-of-memory

I just bought a new game, but unfortunately it causes my PC to hang while starting. Examining `/var/log/kern.log` after forcibly rebooting (ie. hitting the reset button) shows a few of the following errors:

```
[  609.975750] TaskSchedulerBa: page allocation stalls for 12688ms, order:0, mode:0x14201ca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE|__GFP_COLD), nodemask=(null)
[  609.975752] TaskSchedulerBa cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
[  609.975754] CPU: 1 PID: 1905 Comm: TaskSchedulerBa Tainted: G           OE   4.13.0-21-generic #24-Ubuntu
[  609.975755] Hardware name: To Be Filled By O.E.M. To Be Filled By O.E.M./Z77 Extreme4, BIOS P2.80 01/17/2013
[  609.975755] Call Trace:
[  609.975757]  dump_stack+0x63/0x8b
[  609.975759]  warn_alloc+0x114/0x1c0
[  609.975761]  __alloc_pages_slowpath+0x850/0xe30
[  609.975762]  ? get_page_from_freelist+0xa3/0xb20
[  609.975764]  ? crypt_extent+0x112/0x1a0
[  609.975765]  __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x25d/0x280
[  609.975767]  alloc_pages_current+0x6a/0xe0
[  609.975768]  __page_cache_alloc+0x86/0x90
[  609.975769]  filemap_fault+0x214/0x5e0
[  609.975771]  ? filemap_map_pages+0x179/0x320
[  609.975772]  __do_fault+0x1e/0xb0
[  609.975773]  __handle_mm_fault+0xba7/0x1020
[  609.975775]  handle_mm_fault+0xb1/0x200
[  609.975776]  __do_page_fault+0x24d/0x4d0
[  609.975777]  do_page_fault+0x22/0x30
[  609.975778]  page_fault+0x28/0x30
[  609.975779] RIP: 0033:0x7fc84a1ec427
[  609.975779] RSP: 002b:00007fc83685ea00 EFLAGS: 00010202
[  609.975780] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 00007fc83685ea10 RCX: 00007fc847507b9a
[  609.975781] RDX: 00007fc83685ea30 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 00007fc83685ea30
[  609.975781] RBP: 00007fc83685eae0 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000080
[  609.975782] R10: 00007fc83685e9c0 R11: 0000000000000206 R12: 00007fc83685ea18
[  609.975782] R13: 00000a99eba5aa38 R14: 0000000019fa2701 R15: 00007fc84f1e9298
```

I'm not quite sure what this could mean. I'm reading this as the system running out of RAM; however, looking at the game's minimum system requirements (required 6GB, PC has 8GB), the PC should have enough. On the other hand, my graphics card (Intel HD 4000) is not officially supported, but this doesn't seem to be related the error.

Am I really running out of memory here? Is some hardware likely defective? Or is it the integrated graphics?

The system is a fairly up-to-date Ubuntu Artful:

```
~ lsb_release -a      
LSB Version:    core-9.20160110ubuntu5-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu5-noarch:security-9.20160110ubuntu5-amd64:security-9.20160110ubuntu5-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.10
Release:    17.10
Codename:   artful
```

Typical memory situation before starting the game:

```
~ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7678        1321        3992         343        2364        5758
Swap:          7883           0        7883
```

**Edit:** I've been continuously running `free -m` until the freeze; this is the last entry:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7678        3986         129        3348        3562         104
Swap:          7883          42        7840
```

So, while it does seem that the system is really running low on memory, there's still plenty of swap left...